# vb.net - how to keep my main app in focus on desktop?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus

I have an application that is created using windows forms in VB. In my application, I have a button that opens up another (child) form. When that (child) form is closed, my other form (main app form) takes the focus, the only problem is that if I have other applications open on my desktop, when my child form closes, the main parent form goes to the back of my desktop for a second and then comes back to the top. So basically when you close the child form, even if the main form is on top of all of the other apps on the desktop, it will be thrown to the back momentarily and another app will be shown and then my VB app will come back to the top. It lasts for about one second and then comes back on its own, I don't have to do anything to bring it back to the top. It is very annoying. Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: is the child a dialog?  either way, `frmMain.BringToFront`

Comment: Yes, the child is a dialog (modal).

Comment: Then in the code procedure which issues the `frmChild.ShowDialog`, right after that line, add 'Me.BringToFront` or `frmMain.BringToFront` if it is called from a class or modular procedure.

Comment: I have been too tolerant with a person not explaining anything and not defining the problem at all. What initially was "why my main form is on top of my child form?" evolved to "why the paint events of my main form act so weirdly?" IMO, not help-worthy question/attitude.

Comment: How are you closing the child form? Are you sure you're not just hiding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Set the topmost property of the form to true e.g. `Form1.TopMost = True`. In the closing function of the childforms, set this property of your main form. As the form closes the main form should set this property to false and then use `Form/Me.Focus` or `Form/Me.BringToFront` command if you like.